# Сортировка структуры по алфавиту

Tags: c, сортировка, структуры

Уважаемые. Обращаюсь к вам за помощью, пишу программку которая считывает имена и потом сортирует их по алфавиту, смог написать чтоб сортировало структуру по первому слову, но если одинаковое первое слово, то нужно по второму слову, ума не приложу как это реализовать. Помоги, будьте так добры!
Код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define size 50

struct student {
    char meno1[size];
    char meno2[size];
};

int main() {
    struct student natural;
    struct student perepis[size];
    int check = 0;
    while (1) {
        int n;
        n = scanf("%s %s", perepis[check].meno1, perepis[check].meno2);
        if (n == EOF) break;
        check++;
    }
    for (int a = 0; a < check; a++) {
        for (int b = 0; b < check; b++) {
            if (strcmp(perepis[a].meno1, perepis[b].meno1) < 0) {
        natural = perepis[a];
        perepis[a] = perepis[b];
        perepis[b] = natural;
    }         
}
}
    puts("Prijati studenti:");
    for (int g = 0; g < check; g++) {
        printf("%s %s\n", perepis[g].meno1, perepis[g].meno2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcmp(perepis[a].meno1, perepis[b].meno1) < 0
```

заменить на

```
strcmp(perepis[a].meno1, perepis[b].meno1) < 0 || 
(strcmp(perepis[a].meno1, perepis[b].meno1) == 0 && strcmp(perepis[a].meno2, perepis[b].meno2) < 0)
```

Ну, то есть если первые равны - сравнивать вторые...